# Linear gradient generating on border on Apple devices / Safari

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have the following markup:

```css
.hero{
  padding: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gradient{
  background: linear-gradient(195deg, transparent 31%, #FFFFFF 31.2%), linear-gradient(90deg, #79CAF0 0%, #79CAF0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero gradient"></div>
```

Which renders fine on Chrome, Firefox etc. However, on Safari or devices running Mac OS, there's a thin (but noticeable) border being rendered. Like so:

[image]

Notice that line at the bottom of the gradient? Why is that occurring?

Comment: and why using two gradient? you have a a solid color at the bottom layer so simply put it instead of transparent and you will have one gradient

Answer (score 1):

Change the last value from the first gradient from 31.2% to 31% and the line should disappear.

Comment: If I do this, the gradient doesn't come out smooth, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/15La803n/

Comment: Hmm... it seems like there is no other way of smoothing out your angled gradient. However you could try other options like svgs or transform skew like Stripe did on their website: https://stripe.com

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can avoid this with `linear-gradient` at certain angles and color combinations. I’ve run into this myself in the past and had to switch to using SVGs. Let me know if you would like an example of how to do that.

FYI, you can simply the CSS to use a single linear gradient:

```css
.hero{
  padding: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gradient{
  background: linear-gradient(195deg, #79CAF0 31%, transparent 31%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hero gradient"></div>
```